# Retrieve text typed in a field in a variable (with no form submission) Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, email, variables, google-tag-manager

I am using Tag Manager, I made enquiries but I didn't find anything to sort out my issue.

I would like to capture the text (email) that has been typed in a field in a variable, even though the user has not submitted the form. I made an attempt and in the console I do not find the value typed anywhere except in this :

> a.js:6 ~  Call Stack
> mailchimp-woocommerce-public.min.js?ver=2.7.6.01:1 mailchimp.handle_billing_email.request.success
> {"success":true,"email":"testmail@gmail.com","previous":"peterskoech@gmail.com","cart":[]}

How can get back this email using Tag manager ?

Thanks a lot for your help, I am sure someone may have the answer

Best regards

The way to do it, an example

```
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email">E-mail&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="" />           </p>

        
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_password">Mot de passe&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
            </p>

        
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide mailchimp-newsletter"><input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" id="mailchimp_woocommerce_newsletter" type="checkbox" name="mailchimp_woocommerce_newsletter" value="1"> <label for="mailchimp_woocommerce_newsletter" class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox inline"><span>Abonnez-vous à notre newsletter pour bénéficier de conseils bien etre et profiter de promos exclusives ! <br />J’ai lu <a href="https://www.lavilab.com/politique-de-confidentialite/" target="_blank">la politique de confidentialité</a> et consens au traitement de mes données.<br /></span></label></p><div class="clear"></div><p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="birthday_field" data-priority=""><label for="birthday" class="">Date de naissance (pour avoir une surprise)&nbsp;<span class="optional">(facultatif)</span></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="date" class="input-text " name="birthday" id="birthday" placeholder=""  value=""  /></span></p><div class="woocommerce-privacy-policy-text"><p>Vos données personnelles ne seront utilisées que pour le traitement de votre commande, vous accompagner au cours de votre visite du site web, et pour d’autres raisons décrites dans notre <a href="https://www.lavilab.com/politique-de-confidentialite/" class="woocommerce-privacy-policy-link" target="_blank">politique de confidentialité</a>.</p>
```

S’enregistrer

```
    </form>
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide the html or screenshot from the form. The console is from some js function that we can not use in TagManager.